# Change the key binding in eclipse for accepting a code completion suggestion

Tags: java, eclipse, binding

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3oba.png)

I'm using Eclipse on Linux.  Currently when I want to accept a suggestion for code completion, I need to click enter in order to fill it in.  I want to change this so that tab will fill in the suggestion, similar to excel or other languages.  So if I press tab it will accept the suggestion, and then add it to my code.

I've tried looking around in the key binding preferences but could not find an option to do this.  I looked through the content assist a little bit as well.  Anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: Please add all data into the question. If the remote site goes down this question would no longer be understandable.

Comment: I don't think you can currently customize this.

Comment: @nitind dang, tab feels so intuitive